# CKEditor - destroy an instance when the DOM node has been deleted

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Reading through the [CKEditor documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy), I see that they have an option to destroy an instance with `CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName.destroy();`. However, if the DOM has changed, and the whole WYSIWYG DOM structure has been removed, I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
```

...and the following one in Firefox:

```
i.contentWindow is null
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Due to the way my app is structured (loading content via AJAX), I cannot call `.destroy()` when the elements are still on the page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to destroy the ckeditor object and the elemnets in the DOM  AFTER an AJAX call, you can do it by setting a boolean parameter to the function call destroy(true). This way it wont try to update the DOM:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
CKEDITOR.replace(name);
```

I have wrote 2 functions to be able to control these things a bit better. Notice that I have declared a variable before these functions can be used, but there are much slicker ways, but this approach was good enough for the purpose I needed it(I use and need only one instance):

```
    if(typeof(editor) == 'undefined')
        var editor=null;

    function ck_delete(editor)
    {
        if(typeof(editor) != 'undefined' && editor!=null)
            editor.destroy();
    }

    function ck_init(ck_inst_name)
    {
        var el_id=document.getElementById(ck_inst_name);
        if(typeof(el_id) != 'undefined' && el_id!=null)
        {
            if(typeof(editor) == 'undefined' || editor==null)
            {
                editor=CKEDITOR.replace( ck_inst_name );
            }
            else
            {
                ck_delete(editor);
                editor=null;
                editor = CKEDITOR.replace( ck_inst_name );
            }
        }
    }
```

I also check if a HTML element that should be replaced exists so I dont get an error message.

Comment: This solved a similar (the same?) problem for me (replacing ckeditor based on return of AJAX call) but I still get the Uncaught TypeError (same as in the OP).  I'm not sure if there are any side effects but I would like to get rid of the error message.  My code to load the editor is: <code>window.makeCkEditor = function(e, w, h) {
    var cki, config, ei;
    ei = CKEDITOR.instances[e];
    if (ei) ei.destroy(true);
    config = {
      width: w,
      height: h
    };
    return cki = CKEDITOR.replace(e, config);
  };</code>  Any ideas on how I can get rid of the msg?

Comment: @KenThompson: I have a bit different approach, but have you tried to destroy the ck object before the AJAX call?

Comment: Just ran into this problem and as promised, detroy(true) worked to fix the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply one of the patches at http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8226 and it will work. I suggest this one: http://dev.ckeditor.com/attachment/ticket/8226/8226_5.patch

Comment: I'm a little new to the command line; How do I apply this patch? I'm running on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: It might be too complex just to do that. The way that I work is having a SVN copy, it's easy with TortoiseSVN, then using the context menu on the folder use the Patch option and after that you have to repackage all the CKEditor code (so you also need to have Java installed). It's a shame that you are required to do all those steps just because they didn't like the patch and proposed something more complex that in the end hasn't been added.

Comment: Well, since I'm not using SVN, I went through the `patch` file, and made all those changes manually. Now, all those changes were under the `_source` folder. I assume `ckeditor.js` is somehow compiled/concatenated/compressed from all those files. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This doc explains the compression: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/CKPackager But although it states that there's an exe, it seems that you still need the Java environment anyway so I would forget about it.

Comment: It all worked. I don't think you need the Java environment with the `exe`.

Comment: Great. Somebody stated that it didn't work without Java installed, and I trusted him instead of trying to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem integrating CKEDITOR in GWT, in a popup dialog. When the dialog was destroyed, CKEDITOR raised this error - "Cannot read property 'document' of null." The solution was to destroy CKEDITOR before closing the dialog. (We had to extend the GWT ckeditor class in order to override this - using the editor.destroy(true) syntax given by Erik - Thanks, Erik!)